# Cannot assign value of type ‘ViewController‘ to type ‘GADInterstitialDelegate?‘

Tags: swift, admob

I have looked around the answers but I cannot seem to find one for **GADInterstitialDelegate**

I am following the tutorial: https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/interstitial but all I get is this error:

> Cannot assign value of type ‘ViewController‘ to type ‘GADInterstitialDelegate?‘

I have deleted the project and started again. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taken from: [Swift AdMob Tutorial](http://www.ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/swift/display-ads-in-your-application-with-google-admob/)

## Reason

> This means that your ViewController does not conform to the type GADInterstitialDelegate

## Solution

Change your ViewController Class declaration from :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
```

To this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, GADInterstitialDelegate
```